# How to upload 50gb file through SFTP efficiently?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sftp, jsch

I want to implement SFTP client using JSCH java library. I have below queries. Please suggest your ideas.

- How to upload very big files( around 50gb) to SFTP server in best way?
- While doing above operation, there is a high chance of getting error "session timeout". Is there any best way to solve it other than setting the time explicitly?

Comment: You have asked basically the same question already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50903133/850848 - And you never responded to answer and comment you got there.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer very large files at once is always not the best idea. 
One option is to use a bigger buffer, if the upload/download is not used to max. 
But my suggested option is: split up the file automatically or use a tempfile mechanic, which can handle interruptions at transfer (like e.g. jdownloader does)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I know that the append can sometimes a litte bit sh** so large transfers should be avoided. I also know that using different sized buffers can provide better performance for different avg. file sizes. And these optimized buffer sizes can double the speed.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl And how about to be not that rude? If you think I made a mistake than pls tell me why you think I know nothing.

Comment: SFTP is a packet-based protocol. So it effectively already transfers a file in parts. Splitting it further to parts before transfer is just more work, with no real effect.

Comment: Packets and parts are not the same thing. If a part fails it might be retransfered completely. If you use split up the large file than you will loose way less time in retransfering and if the transfer interrupts by session timeout (like in the question) or other reasons (sh*** internet connection) then it might be the just better solution to use a split up or an own managed buffered split up transfer stuff, since it maybe is the only way the transfer will work at all if the connection is that bad.

Comment: You can resume transfer with SFTP. No need to split the transfer for that. Also there's no way to merge the uploaded parts with most SFTP servers.